# How to allow incoming from other subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an ELB for an Elastic Beanstalk.

I want to allow an incoming port from an EC2 instance resides in other subnet.

Currently I allowed `0.0.0.0/0`.

I want it removed from my rules. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your CIDR block of the other subnet, but you can change the rule to contain the mask of your subnet.

e.g. if your CIDR was 10.0.0.0/16 (allowing 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.1.254) then you could set it to be:

`10.0.0.0/16` or if you only wanted the range within a particular subnet (say 10.0.1.0 - 10.0.1.154) then you would set it to `10.0.1.0/24`